# Settings option on click of Menu button - Launcher

Tags: android

I am successfully making a launcher, but i need to add another settings option. When i click on the menu button it will show. When you click on it, it goes to an activity.

For example. In the default launcher, when you hit menu on a home screen you can add, or set a wallpaper, ect. When you click on wallpaper it takes you to change the wallpaper.

What i need to do is create a button like that under the menu, and when it is clicked take me to an activity.

---

### Here is part of my Launcher.Java...

```
    private static final int MENU_GROUP_ADD = 1;
    private static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int MENU_WALLPAPER_SETTINGS = MENU_ADD + 1;
    private static final int MENU_MYHOME_SETTINGS = MENU_WALLPAPER_SETTINGS + 1;
    private static final int MENU_SEARCH = MENU_MYHOME_SETTINGS + 1;
    private static final int MENU_STYLES = MENU_SEARCH + 1;
    private static final int MENU_SETTINGS = MENU_STYLES + 1;
```

---

### And here is the other part

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
menu.add(MENU_GROUP_ADD, MENU_ADD, 0, R.string.menu_add).setIcon(
        android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add).setAlphabeticShortcut('A');
menu.add(0, MENU_WALLPAPER_SETTINGS, 0, R.string.menu_wallpaper).setIcon(
        android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery).setAlphabeticShortcut('W');
menu.add(0, MENU_MYHOME_SETTINGS, 0, R.string.myhome_settings).setIcon(
        R.drawable.ic_menu_customize);
menu.add(0, MENU_SEARCH, 0, R.string.menu_search).setIcon(
        android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default).setAlphabeticShortcut(
        SearchManager.MENU_KEY);
menu.add(0, MENU_STYLES, 0, R.string.menu_customize).setIcon(
        R.drawable.ic_menu_customize);
```

---

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the menu clicks in overriden method onOptionsMenuSelected(MenuItem item). It might look like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_ADD:
            doSomething();
            return true;
        case MENU_WALLPAPER_SETTINGS:
            doSomethingElse();
            return true;
            // All other buttons here, each in it's own case
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyAnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu for more information about menus and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity for Activities and how to start them.